# How can I make my GTFS queries run faster?

Tags: mysql, gtfs

I'm trying to play with a GTFS database, namely the one provided by the RATP for Paris and its suburbs.

The set of data is *huge*. The `stop_times` table has 14 million rows.

Here's the tables schemas: https://github.com/mauryquijada/gtfs-mysql/blob/master/gtfs-sql.sql

I'm trying to get the most efficient way to get the available routes at a specific location. As far as I understand the GTFS spec, here are the tables and their links from my data (lat/lon) to the routes:

```
stops      | stop_times     | trips      | routes
-----------+----------------+------------+--------------
lat        | stop_id        | trip_id    | route_id
lon        | trip_id        | route_id   |
stop_id    |                |            |
```

I have compiled what I want in three steps (actually the three links we have between the four tables above), published under this gist for clarity: https://gist.github.com/BenoitDuffez/4eba85e3598ebe6ece5f

---

Here's how I created this script.

I have been able to quickly find all the stops within a walking distance (say, 200m) in less than a second. I use:

```
$ . mysql.ini && time mysql -h $host -N -B -u $user -p${pass} $name -e "SELECT stop_id, (6371000*acos(cos(radians(48.824699))*cos(radians(s.stop_lat))*cos(radians(2.3243)-radians(s.stop_lon))+sin(radians(48.824699))*sin(radians(s.stop_lat)))) AS distance
FROM stops s
GROUP BY s.stop_id
HAVING distance < 200
ORDER BY distance ASC" | awk '{print $1}'
3705271
4472979
4036891
4036566
3908953
3908755
3900765
3900693
3900607
4473141
3705272
4472978
4036892
4036472
4035057
3908952
3705288
3908814
3900832
3900672
3900752
3781623
3781622

real    0m0.797s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Then, getting all the stop_times later today (with ``` stop_times.departure_time > '``date +%T``' ```) takes a lot of time:

```
"SELECT trip_id
 FROM stop_times
 WHERE
     stop_id IN ($stops) AND departure_time >= '$now'

 GROUP BY trip_id"
```

With `$stops` containing the list of stops obtained from the first step. Here's an example:

```
$ . mysql.ini && time mysql -h $host -N -B -u $user -p${pass} $name -e "SELECT stop_id, (6371000*acos(cos(radians(
FROM stops s
GROUP BY s.stop_id
HAVING distance < 200
ORDER BY distance ASC" | awk '{print $1}'
3705271
4472979
4036891
4036566
3908953
...
9916360850964321
9916360920964320
9916360920964321

real    1m21.399s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

There are more than 2000 lines in this result.

My last step was to select all routes that match these `trip_id`s. It's quite easy, and rather fast:

```
$ . mysql.ini && time mysql -h $host -u $user -p${pass} $name -e "SELECT r.id, r.route_long_name FROM trips t, routes r WHERE t.trip_id IN (`cat trip_ids | tr '\n' '#' | sed -e 's/##$//' -e 's/#/,/g'`) AND r.route_id = t.route_id GROUP BY t.route_id"
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | route_long_name                                                         |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  290 | (PLACE DE CLICHY <-> CHATILLON METRO) - Aller                           |
|  291 | (PLACE DE CLICHY <-> CHATILLON METRO) - Retour                          |
|  404 | (PORTE D'ORLEANS-METRO <-> ECOLE VETERINAIRE DE MAISON-ALFORT) - Aller  |
|  405 | (PORTE D'ORLEANS-METRO <-> ECOLE VETERINAIRE DE MAISON-ALFORT) - Retour |
|  453 | (PORTE D'ORLEANS-METRO <-> LYCEE POLYVALENT) - Retour                   |
|  457 | (PORTE D'ORLEANS-METRO <-> LYCEE POLYVALENT) - Retour                   |
|  479 | (PORTE D'ORLEANS-METRO <-> VELIZY 2) - Retour                           |
|  810 | (PLACE DE LA LIBERATION <-> GARE MONTPARNASSE) - Aller                  |
|  989 | (PORTE D'ORLEANS-METRO) - Retour                                        |
| 1034 | (PLACE DE LA LIBERATION <-> HOTEL DE VILLE DE PARIS_4E__AR) - Aller     |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+

real    0m1.070s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

With here the file `trip_ids` containing the 2k trip IDs.

How can I get this result faster? Is there a better way to crawl through the data rather than the `stops>stop_times>trips>routes` path I have taken?

The total time here is around 30s for actually ONE 'query': "What are the routes available 200m from this location?". That's too much...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table schema I used was plain wrong, I should've built it myself or at least analyze it before using it.

Here's an updated schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `agency` (
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    agency_id VARCHAR(100),
    agency_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    agency_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    agency_timezone VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    agency_lang VARCHAR(100),
    agency_phone VARCHAR(100),
    agency_fare_url VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (agency_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `calendar_dates` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    service_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `date` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    exception_type TINYINT(2) NOT NULL,
    KEY `service_id` (service_id),
    KEY `exception_type` (exception_type)    
);

CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    service_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    monday TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    tuesday TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    wednesday TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    thursday TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    friday TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    saturday TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    sunday TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    start_date VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
    end_date VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    KEY `service_id` (service_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `fare_attributes` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    fare_id VARCHAR(100),
    price VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    currency_type VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    payment_method TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    transfers TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    transfer_duration VARCHAR(10),
    exception_type TINYINT(2) NOT NULL,
    agency_id INT(100),
    KEY `fare_id` (fare_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `fare_rules` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    fare_id VARCHAR(100),
    route_id VARCHAR(100),
    origin_id VARCHAR(100),
    destination_id VARCHAR(100),
    contains_id VARCHAR(100),
    KEY `fare_id` (fare_id),
    KEY `route_id` (route_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `feed_info` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    feed_publisher_name VARCHAR(100),
    feed_publisher_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    feed_lang VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    feed_start_date VARCHAR(8),
    feed_end_date VARCHAR(8),
    feed_version VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE `frequencies` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    trip_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    start_time VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    end_time VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    headway_secs VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    exact_times TINYINT(1),
    KEY `trip_id` (trip_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `routes` (
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    route_id VARCHAR(100),
    agency_id VARCHAR(50),
    route_short_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    route_long_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    route_type VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, 
    route_text_color VARCHAR(255),
    route_color VARCHAR(255),
    route_url VARCHAR(255),
    route_desc VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (route_id),
    KEY `agency_id` (agency_id),
    KEY `route_type` (route_type),
    CONSTRAINT `agency_id` FOREIGN KEY (`agency_id`) REFERENCES `agency` (`agency_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `shapes` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    shape_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    shape_pt_lat DECIMAL(8,6) NOT NULL,
    shape_pt_lon DECIMAL(8,6) NOT NULL,
    shape_pt_sequence TINYINT(3) NOT NULL,
    shape_dist_traveled VARCHAR(50),
    KEY `shape_id` (shape_id)
);

CREATE TABLE `stops` (
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    stop_id VARCHAR(255),
    stop_code VARCHAR(50),
    stop_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    stop_desc VARCHAR(255),
    stop_lat DECIMAL(10,6) NOT NULL,
    stop_lon DECIMAL(10,6) NOT NULL,
    zone_id VARCHAR(255),
    stop_url VARCHAR(255),
    location_type VARCHAR(2),
    parent_station VARCHAR(100),
    stop_timezone VARCHAR(50),
    wheelchair_boarding TINYINT(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (stop_id),
    KEY `zone_id` (zone_id),
    KEY `stop_lat` (stop_lat),
    KEY `stop_lon` (stop_lon),
    KEY `location_type` (location_type),
    KEY `parent_station` (parent_station)
);

CREATE TABLE `trips` (
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    route_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    service_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    trip_id VARCHAR(255),
    trip_headsign VARCHAR(255),
    trip_short_name VARCHAR(255),
    direction_id TINYINT(1), #0 for one direction, 1 for another.
    block_id VARCHAR(11),
    shape_id VARCHAR(11),
    wheelchair_accessible TINYINT(1), #0 for no information, 1 for at least one rider accommodated on wheel chair, 2 for no riders accommodated.
    bikes_allowed TINYINT(1), #0 for no information, 1 for at least one bicycle accommodated, 2 for no bicycles accommodated
    PRIMARY KEY (trip_id),
    KEY `route_id` (route_id),
    KEY `service_id` (service_id),
    KEY `direction_id` (direction_id),
    KEY `block_id` (block_id),
    KEY `shape_id` (shape_id),
    CONSTRAINT `route_id` FOREIGN KEY (`route_id`) REFERENCES `routes` (`route_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `service_id` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `calendar` (`service_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `stop_times` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    trip_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    arrival_time VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    arrival_time_seconds INT(100),
    departure_time VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    departure_time_seconds INT(100),
    stop_id VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    stop_sequence VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    stop_headsign VARCHAR(50),
    pickup_type VARCHAR(2),
    drop_off_type VARCHAR(2),
    shape_dist_traveled VARCHAR(50),
    KEY `trip_id` (trip_id),
    KEY `arrival_time_seconds` (arrival_time_seconds),
    KEY `departure_time_seconds` (departure_time_seconds),
    KEY `stop_id` (stop_id),
    KEY `stop_sequence` (stop_sequence),
    KEY `pickup_type` (pickup_type),
    KEY `drop_off_type` (drop_off_type),
    CONSTRAINT `trip_id` FOREIGN KEY (`trip_id`) REFERENCES `trips` (`trip_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `stop_id` FOREIGN KEY (`stop_id`) REFERENCES `stops` (`stop_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `transfers` (
    id INT(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    transit_system VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    from_stop_id INT(100) NOT NULL,
    to_stop_id VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
    transfer_type TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    min_transfer_time VARCHAR(100)
);
```

I've put the `xyz_id` keys as `PRIMARY KEY` in their own table and as `FOREIGN KEY` in the others.
I still have some optimizations to make to this schema.

Now this query works in less than 1-5 seconds:

```
SELECT
    s.stop_id,
    (6371000*acos(cos(radians(48.1128135))*cos(radians(s.stop_lat))*cos(radians(-1.6470705)-radians(s.stop_lon))+sin(radians(48.1128135))*sin(radians(s.stop_lat)))) AS distance,
    t.route_id,
    st.*,
    t.*,
    r.*,
    c.*

FROM stop_times st

LEFT JOIN stops s USING (stop_id)
LEFT JOIN trips t USING (trip_id)
LEFT JOIN routes r USING (route_id)

LEFT JOIN calendar c ON c.service_id = t.service_id 

where
    c.start_date <= 20140915
    and c.end_date >= 20140915
    and c.sunday = 1

    and st.departure_time > '15:00:00'

HAVING
    distance < 200

ORDER BY st.departure_time ASC
```

Comment: Actually the spec doesn't mention the type, so we can only assume `VARCHAR`. That's beyond my understanding, as integer keys are so much faster.

Comment: In your `shapes` table should the `shape_pt_lon DECIMAL(8,6)` actually be `DECIMAL(9,6)` to account for the `-180 to 180` range? (Although this may not be necessary for the data you have)

Comment: You're right, I did notice that bug a while ago and fixed it. I didn't bother to edit my code here.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: Use table joins and indices.

Here's the longer answer:

You have the right idea here and your understanding of how the tables relate to one another is  correct. However, by asking the DBMS to match field values from a list (using `WHERE...IN`) rather than joining tables together you are requiring it do a lot more work than it needs to.

What you really want to do is execute all this as a single query, using `JOIN` clauses to link the tables together. Try this, which additionally joins the `calendars` and `calendar_dates` tables to limit the results to only routes actually operating today:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id, r.route_long_name
  FROM (SELECT s.stop_id, (6371000 *
          acos(cos(radians(48.824699)) * cos(radians(s.stop_lat)) *
          cos(radians(2.3243) - radians(s.stop_lon)) +
          sin(radians(48.824699)) * sin(radians(s.stop_lat)))) AS distance
          FROM stops AS s) AS i_s
  INNER JOIN stop_times AS st ON st.stop_id = i_s.stop_id
  INNER JOIN (SELECT trip_id, route_id FROM trips AS t
                INNER JOIN (SELECT service_id FROM calendars
                              WHERE start_date <= '2014-09-09'
                                AND end_date >= '2014-09-09'
                                AND tuesday = 1
                              UNION
                                SELECT service_id FROM calendar_dates
                                  WHERE date = '2014-09-09'
                                    AND exception_type = 1
                              EXCEPT
                                SELECT service_id FROM calendar_dates
                                  WHERE date = '2014-09-09'
                                    AND exception_type = 2) AS c
                   ON c.service_id = t.service_id) AS t_r
    ON t_r.trip_id = st.trip_id
  INNER JOIN routes AS r ON r.route_id = t_r.route_id
  WHERE st.departure_time > '$now'
    AND i_s.distance < 200;
```

Here `INNER JOIN` is used to "add in" the columns of another table, including only those rows that match the condition in the `ON` clause. This should be *much* faster than generating a list of results with one query and then feeding it in to the next.

To get even better performance, though, you will want to create indices that prevent the DBMS having to scan linearly through tables. The rule of thumb is to have an index defined for each column used in either a `JOIN` or a `WHERE` clause. Here are the indices I defined, which you should find make the above query perform quite well:

```
CREATE INDEX calendar_dates_date_exception_type_service_id_index
  ON calendar_dates (date, exception_type, service_id);

CREATE INDEX trips_service_id_trip_id_route_id_index
  ON trips (service_id, trip_id, route_id);

CREATE INDEX stop_times_trip_id_departure_time_stop_id_index
  ON stop_times (trip_id, departure_time, stop_id);

CREATE INDEX routes_route_id_index ON routes (route_id);

CREATE INDEX stops_stop_id_index ON stops (stop_id);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot for the quick reply. I already tried using `LEFT JOIN` which took forever (actually I don't know, I `Ctrl-C`ed the query). Your query took 53 seconds, which is way better than all my queries together. Adding the indices took... well, it's been minutes now and they're not created yet. Stay tuned!

Comment: Well, I'm confused. I removed the indices on `departure_time` as they failed (several stops may share the same departure time). I continued working on my script, which gives results in less than a minute. However your query yields an empty result set. Please have a look at here, for the sake of clarity: https://gist.github.com/BenoitDuffez/4eba85e3598ebe6ece5f (admittedly, it's much later now, so it's searching on departure times later than 23h50, which means much less results)

Comment: Actually that was fair. I tested using departure time hard-coded to `18:30:00`, I'm getting the results that we see in my question in 36 seconds.

Comment: So the query I posted above is returning results after all? I've updated my answer with a new index definition to try---hopefully this will serve as a covering index and discourage MySQL from doing a full scan on the `stops` table, which I suspect is where it's spending most of its time currently.

Comment: Another thing I'll mention: Really our queries should be joining the `calendars` and `calendar_dates` tables as well to limit the results to only routes running _today_. (See [my answer to "GTFS query to include calendar exceptions"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24100803/473305).)

Comment: No, there's no result from your query. I rewrote it in a slightly different way, still no results. Yet my scripts runs fine. I have updated my gist so that it includes a script that I used to build the database. Careful though, this will send 751MB of data to the server, and the resulting InnoDB space used is more than 2.6GB. // PS: Good catch for the calendar. I'll have to add this join! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks. I'm at a disadvantage doing all this in my head. Let me see if I can figure out why that query is failing.

Comment: Benoit, I've updated my answer with a new query and index definitions that you should find both work and are significantly faster.

Comment: Thanks. However I'm using MySQL which doesn't support `EXCEPT`, AFAICT. I don't know how to rewrite your query :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60939/discussion-between-benoit-duffez-and-simon-south).

Answer (score -1):

I can only tell you that I tried the same thing with SQL, and it took forever, so I had to write a script, first in Perl (no gain), then in C++ (gain 35× faster).

Comment: This should have been a comment and does not answer the question.